# How many six digit even numbers can be formed with 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9? (no repetition)

Tags: combinatorics, permutations

I'm trying to figure out how to do this permutation task.

So I have the numbers 1, 3, 4, 6, 7, 9 and I need to find out the possible amount of even six digit numbers I can make with them. The numbers can't repeat themselves.

So I know that the calculation would have only two possibilities on the units slot, like

```
x * x * x * x * x * 2
```

I thought I could just fill the remaining slots with the total amount minus one and decrease afterwards, so it'd be

```
5 * 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 2
```

Which gives me 240, but I'm not sure if that's correct.

Is that right?

Comment: Yes, this is correct. You choose 2 for the units place, then 5! for a random permutation of the rest.

Comment: I thought I would have to remove 2 from the first spot, but the result I was getting was not one of the alternatives.

Comment: I'm afraid I don't understand what you're saying.

Comment: Since I have 2 for the units spot, I thought I would have to take two numbers from the total amount to make the fatorial

Comment: So I thought I would have something like 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1 * 2 but that didn't make any sense

Comment: I see what you mean. The factorial is a permutation of the remaining five elements. Since you are only taking one of the 2 or 4 each time, you still have to permute the remaining 5 numbers.